# Spring Transactions without Datasource but persisting to database

Tags: xml, junit, transactions, weblogic

I have a strange scenario. I have a Spring MVC ( no UI though) just services to support uploading some XML files to database. But, the database connection is provided by some legacy code (no "datasource" available directly) with helper methods such as `getConnection()`, `createCallableStatement()`, `executeBatch()` etc...
But the code will be deployed on to WebLogic (very tricky and the decision was made to this way) I am required to have transactions as these files have many scenarios where I need to rollback if needed. Now, how do I do this using Spring Transaction support? I also need to make it work for jUnits.
I am not using any ORM framework but plain JDBC ( it is a specialcase again).

Can someone please give me some pointers on how to implement this. I have created a profile "WebLogic" in my Srring context and created a bean transactionManager but transaction are not being rolled back for exceptions as the transaction manager doesn't have the datasource to monitor and roll back.I am not able to figure out a way how to do this for jUnits also.

Sample context.xml is as follows:

```
<beans profile="WebLogic">
    <bean id="transactionManager"class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager"></bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: <beans profile="WebLogic">
  <bean id="transactionManager"
   class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager">
  </bean>
 </beans>

Comment: Thank you for editing xml to a readable format.

Comment: Anybody, please help me with this.

Comment: finally , the team decided to change the way the datasource is obtained. I now have access to Datasource and the problem is now resolved.